# Returning null when passing a string value of one view to label in other view in iphone?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have to pass a string value from one view to a label in other view. But when I do such thing the label value is null. Could not understand where I am going wrong? Here is my code:

In FirstViewController.m

```
SecondViewController *gp=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
gp.d.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nam];
[self.view addSubview:gp.view];
[gp release];
```

In SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    UILabel *d;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *d;
```

In SecondViewController.m
    @synthesize d;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSString *urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.0.108:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ICloudServices/AppointmentService/json/GetProviders/?cid={%@}", [d text]];
}
```

But here the value of d is not passed. Why I dont understand. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use an NSString to pass the value to the second viewController.

Comment: View Controller IBOutlet memory gets changed.So use an NSString to pass the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of passing value to IBOutlet UILablel before adding subview is not allocated (has no memory reference).

So better way is to pass your value after adding subView.

```
[self.view addSubview:gp.view];
gp.d.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nam];
```

**EDIT**: better way is to pass string is like this:

```
Create property of NSString in SecondViewController say yourString.
```

Now

```
SecondViewController *gp=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
gp.yourString = [nam retain];
[self.view addSubview:gp.view];
```

Now in viewDidLoad of SecondViewController do this:

```
self.d.text = self.yourString;
```

Use yourString anywhere as per your requirement.

Comment: Hey I got it in a Label but when I try to use the same value in a service url in DidLoad() then the value is not passed.This is what Iam doing...In SecondViewController.m- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   
    NSString *urlString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.108:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ICloudServices/AppointmentService/json/GetProviders/?cid={%@}",[d text]]; Here I couldn't get the value of d. Can u please tell y is it so?

Comment: @Prince...Thank a lot .I got it.